# How to override a jQuery bind for a child element?

Tags: jquery, forms, binding, jquery-selectors, scroll

I have mouse actions triggering a custom function on the html and body, however the scroll bars and a form I have on the page has now become unresponsive to mouse clicks!

```
$('html,body').bind('mousedown mouseup mouseover mousemove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //this is required :(
    customFunction();
});
```

(Why do I need prevent default? full customFunction [here](http://jsfiddle.net/upEAx/))

How do I preserve the body binding while keeping the form usable and the scroll bars functioning?

I have a **JSFiddle demo** here, showing exactly what is happening:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ywg9T/

Comment: what is the purpose of doing e.preventDefault()? What do you want to prevent?

Comment: You can use `e.target` to find out what is directly under the mouse, and conditionally check to avoid preventDefault on certain elements.

Comment: Maybe `event.stopPropagation()` will help? Test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/9WCcz/) to see if this is what you need!

Comment: @Ergec: I'm using a custom cursor class (a grabby hand), in chrome if you don't prevent default the cursor turns into a text-selection tool instead and disrupts the grabby hand custom cursor, halting the script altogether. script here: http://jsfiddle.net/upEAx/

Comment: @Ben Lee, I'm a beginner programmer could you please provide an example so I'd understand better? Thank you. Maybe you could even post it as an answer.

Comment: @Shef: I tried it here and it doesn't seem to work, but thank you! http://jsfiddle.net/upEAx/1/

Comment: @Mohammad: That code doesn't seem to work even without `e.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: @Shef: I know, it only worked with `e.preventDefault();` but this post has now been updated with a working answer. Please look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in jQuery, related to the event for starting a selection. It fires way too frequently. There is a ticket filed for it, and it scheduled to be fixed in 1.8. In the meantime, you can fix this problem by hackily removing that event handler (where 'element' is the element you want to disable it for -- in your case, the whole document):

```
element.onselectstart = function () { return false; };
```

Then you don't have to do `preventDefault`. So, your code would look something like this:

```
document.onselectstart = function () { return false; };
(function($){
    var drag = false;
    $("#click").bind('mousedown mouseup mouseover mousemove', function(e) {
        if(e.type === 'mouseover'){ ... }
        if(e.type === 'mousemove'){ ... }
        if(e.type === 'mousedown'){ ... }
        if(e.type === 'mouseup'){ ... }
    });
})(jQuery);
```